# Error when trying to use SQL query from MySQL dump into MSSQL 2012

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I am trying to load an SQL dump from MySQL into MSSQL 2012. I used the MySQL export option in PHPMyAdmin and selected MSSQL as the format type of the SQL. I am now trying to load this SQL in by running a new query in SQL Server Management Studio 2012 by running a new query.

When trying to run a query such as the one below:

```
INSERT INTO `F` (`date`, `open`, `high`, `low`, `close`, `volume`, `amount_change`,`percent_change`) VALUES
('2012-12-19', 11.79, 11.85, 11.62, 11.73, 54884700, -0.06, -0.508906)
```

I get the error message: 
    (Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 51
    Incorrect syntax near '`'.)

Line 51 is the second line of the code shown. Any ideas on how I can fix this?

Many thanks.

Answer (score 0):

See [this `SQL Server` documentation](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176027%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) on delimiters: you need to replace backtics (`) with double-quotes (") or square brackets ([]):

```
INSERT INTO [F] (
    [date],
    [open],
    [high],
    [low],
    [close],
    [volume],
    [amount_change],[percent_change]
) VALUES (
    '2012-12-19',
    11.79,
    11.85,
    11.62,
    11.73,
    54884700,
    -0.06,
    -0.508906
)
```

Comment: Thanks for that, my database has a 100,000 rows, would you happen to know the best way of getting that format?

Comment: @user2694239, [MySQL manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-backup-excerpt/5.0/en/mysqldump-delimited-text.html) says there is an `--fields-enclosed-by` option to `mysqldump`. That's your best bet.